# List с очень большим размером вызывает лаги, и в целом долго грузится

Tags: java, android, list, android-asynctask

у меня в приложении есть метод который математическими вычислениями находит определенные координаты, так вот, храню я все эти данные в List<> и приходится работать с этими данными, и тут проблема, лист очень длинный и во-первых он без AsyncTask интерфейс зависает, а во-вторых поместив код в AsyncTask, операция начинается тогда когда, List уже загружен, а это очень долго, так вот, есть ли способы обойти лаги. Сразу говорю, лист в одно время не весь нужен, Допустим: половина нужна сейчас, а половина через пять минут. Есть идеи? м?

```
public static List<MyLoc> start(List<MyLoc> points){
    List<MyLoc> myLocList = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i <= points.size() - 1; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) != points.size()) {
            int p = 250000;
            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
                List<MyLoc> list = fetch(points.get(i), points.get(i + 1), p);

                list.add(list.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return myLocList;
}
```

В общем, если пояснить, то на вход принимает тоже List с меньшим кол-во данным, и выполняются операции, размер List увеличивается, до очень больших значений (300 минимум 25-30к максимум, а то и больше). И возвращает List.

Comment: приведите пример list, хотя бы несколько элементов

Comment: Видимо, неправильно выстроена логика доступа к данным и алгоритм работы в целом. Однако вопрос слишком общий, нужна конкретизация

Comment: Для этого случая пытаются применить паттерн flyweight. Основная идея того, состоит в том, чтобы вынести повторяющиеся части объектов листа в отдельные объекты и вынести их в хранилище, после чего ссылаться на них, по такому типо часто выносят enum(как пример)

Comment: Добавил код в пост.

Comment: ищите алгоритмы для разбиения листа на группы, например для координатных классов что-нибудь типа "Дерево квадрантов"

Comment: т.е. нефиг бегать по листу. Возможно у объектов должны быть ссылки на соседей, тогда не придется искать их каждый раз. Ну и вообще 90%, что не верно выстроена главная архитектура. В целом вам помочь возможно только зная все о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двойной цикл это всегда затратно по времени. Часто его можно заменить более быстрым алгоритмом, со временем O(N*log(N)) за счет предварительной сортировки.

Но сначала я бы убедился, что List это ArrayList, а не LinkedList, потому что операция get() у LinkedList очень медленная.

Ну и строчку

```
List<MyLoc> list = fetch(points.get(i), points.get(i + 1), p);
```

я бы вынес из внутреннего цикла, она же от `j` не зависит.

Останется код, который вызывает недоумение:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
            list.add(list.get(j));
        }
```

то есть, к `list` добавили все его элементы, получили удвоенный набор. Зачем?